# How to delete an item from this listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a listbox where i need to be able to remove individual **RegimeItems**.  These **RegimItems** belong to a specific user, but as they are right now the listbox shows them for specific user, so i don't know if i need to state that in the code. Currently it is showing no error however it does not return the listbox with the remaining **RegimeItems**, nor does it actually update the database with the changes.

**Update**: i am getting a null reference exception at`model.RequestedSelected` on the line `foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)` in RemoveExercises.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(int? id, UserExerciseViewModel vmodel)
{
    User user = db.Users.Find(id);
    UserExerciseViewModel model = new UserExerciseViewModel { AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises(), RequestedExercises = ChosenExercises(user, vmodel) };
    user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(UserExerciseViewModel model, string add, string remove, string send, int id, RegimeItem regimeItem)
{
    User user = db.Users.Find(id);
    user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;
    RestoreSavedState(model);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
        AddExercises(model, id);
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remove))
        RemoveExercises(model, id);              
    SaveState(model);
    return View(model);
}

void SaveState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
{
    model.SavedRequested = string.Join(",", model.RequestedExercises.Select(p => p.RegimeItemID.ToString()).ToArray());
    model.AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises().ToList();
}

void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
{
    foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)
{
    RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);
    if (item != null)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        user.RegimeItems.Remove(item);
    }
    RedirectToAction("ExerciseIndex");
}

void RestoreSavedState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
{
    model.RequestedExercises = new List<RegimeItem>();

    //get the previously stored items
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SavedRequested))
    {
        string[] exIds = model.SavedRequested.Split(',');
        var exercises = GetAllExercises().Where(p => exIds.Contains(p.ExerciseID.ToString()));
        model.AvailableExercises.AddRange(exercises);
    }
}

private List<Exercise> GetAllExercises()
{
    return db.Exercises.ToList();
}

private List<RegimeItem> ChosenExercises(User user, UserExerciseViewModel model)
{
    return db.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID)
    .SelectMany(u => u.RegimeItems)
    .ToList();
}
```

**Models**

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RegimeItem> RegimeItems { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        this.RegimeItems = new List<RegimeItem>();
    } 
}
public class RegimeItem
{
    public int RegimeItemID { get; set; }
    public Exercise RegimeExercise { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class UserExerciseViewModel
{
    public List<Exercise> AvailableExercises { get; set; }
    public List<RegimeItem> RequestedExercises { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedExercise { get; set; }
    public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
    public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
    public string SavedRequested { get; set; }
}
```

**View**(Segment only)

```
      <input type="submit" name="remove"
             id="remove" value="<<" />
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
      @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RequestedExercises, new MultiSelectList(Model.RequestedExercises, "RegimeItemID", "RegimeExercise.Name", Model.RequestedSelected))
  </td>
```

Comment: model.RequestedExercises is a List<Project.Model.RegimeItem>, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model.RequestedExercises list doesn't have a RegimeItemID property. It's a list of items. I suspect what you actually want is more like:

```
foreach(int selected in RequestedSelected)
{
   RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);
   if(item != null)
   {
      User user = db.Users.Find(id);
      user.RegimeItems.Remove(item);
   }
}
```

Hopefully, this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks Matty, i think `RequestedSelected` should be in place of `whatEverID` however im recieving `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int[]'`.  Im just trying to remove an item by selecting it in the listbox then hitting the remove button to delete it from the db.

Comment: RequestedSelected is an array of integers. Does this represent each item that is to be removed?

Comment: Yes i believe it does. I have the same for the list of avilable exercises too, as this is a part of a dual listbox system.

Comment: Im getting: `A local variable named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'i', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.` and `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'FaceToFace.Model.RegimeItem'` Does that mean that RequestedSelected doesn't represent each item to be removed. I just thought it was the integer that was allocated to RegimeItemID in the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks Matty, it's no longer showing errors however i got a null reference exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the foreach line however i believe that's probably a mistake on my part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77221/discussion-between-matty-m-and-nilmag).